# matching answers from qiuz to question id

Tags: php, html, pdo

In my website I have a quiz. The way the questions are created is that the admin can log in and add questions with the options and the answers to go with them. I get the questions down from the database they are stored in like so:

```
<form action="score.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Name*:</strong><br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" required value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Email Address:</strong><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?php
        try {

            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT questionID, question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD FROM quiz WHERE editedBy = "admin" ORDER BY questionID ');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    echo '<h3>'.$row['question'].'</h3>';
                    echo '<ol>';
                    echo '<li>
                                       <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].' value = '.$row['optionA'].'/> '.$row['optionA'].'</li>';
                    echo '<li>
                                        <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].'  value = '.$row['optionB'].'/> '.$row['optionB'].'</li>';
                    echo '<li>
                                        <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].'   value = '.$row['optionC'].'/> '.$row['optionC'].'</li>';
                    echo '<li>
                                        <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].' value = '.$row['optionD'].'/> '.$row['optionD'].'</li>';
                    echo '</ol>';
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
    </div>

            <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

</form>
```

As can be seen the questions are in a form and once the user is finished taking the quiz they hit submit which will redirect them to score.php.

My question how do I go about matching the answer given by the user to the question id to determine whether they were correct or not? Been trying to look up how to do this but haven't got a clue as to where to start. Any help would be much appreciated!

So I now have updated my code so it will pass the question id to score.php like so:

```
        try {

            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT questionID, question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD FROM quiz WHERE editedBy = "admin" ORDER BY questionID ');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    echo '<h3>'.$row['question'].'</h3>';
                    echo '<ol>';
                    echo '<li>
                                       <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].' value = '.$row['optionA'].'> '.$row['optionA'].' required</li>';
                    echo '<li>
                                        <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].'  value = '.$row['optionB'].'> '.$row['optionB'].'</li>';
                    echo '<li>
                                        <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].'   value = '.$row['optionC'].'> '.$row['optionC'].'</li>';
                    echo '<li>
                                        <input type="radio" name= '.$row['questionID'].' value = '.$row['optionD'].'> '.$row['optionD'].'</li>';
                    echo '
                                        <input type="hidden" name= "question" value = '.$row['questionID'].'>
                    echo '</ol>';
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

just for testing in score.php I have done this:

```
$answer = $_POST['question'];

echo $answer;
```

When I do this however, it will just display the id of the last question, am I passing this through correctly? And if so where do I go from here for testing the answer given by someone?

Comment: Where is the correct answer stored? Is it in the quiz table aswell?

Comment: yes, answer is stored in the table

Comment: So when the admin adds a question to the quiz they need to enter the question, the 4 different options and then the correct answer. This is all stored in the same row of the quiz table

Comment: You need a hidden input, which would send the `questionId` to score.php

Comment: I've done that now as seen in my updated question but where do I go from here?

Comment: Are you able to help me @hjpotter92?